# Django error "argument of type 'ForeignKey' is not iterable"

Tags: python, django

The following code is erroring on the line indicated (near the end with "<==="), or possibly on the line after that:

```
class InspectModelUpdated(InspectModel):
    """
    Updated for compatibility with Django 1.10 +
    Replaced the get_all_field_names and get_field_by_name methods,
    which have been removed from the Model._meta API.
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api
    """
    def update_fields(self):
        """Set the list of django.db.models fields

        Three different types of fields:
        * standard model fields: Char, Integer...
        * relation fields: OneToOne (back and forth), ForeignKey,
          and GenericForeignKey
        * many fields: ManyToMany (back and forth)

        """
        self.fields = set()
        self.relation_fields = set()
        self.many_fields = set()
        opts = getattr(self.model, '_meta', None)
        if opts:
            for field in opts.get_fields():
                model = field.model
                direct = not field.auto_created or field.concrete
                m2m = field.many_to_many
                if not direct:  # relation or many field from another model
                    name = field.get_accessor_name()

                    field = field.field                                           <==============
                    jr_rel = field.rel if 'rel' in field else field.remote_field
                    if jr_rel.multiple:  # m2m or fk to this model
                        self._add_item(name, self.many_fields)
                    else:  # one to one
                        self._add_item(name, self.relation_fields)
```

I added a debug dump just before this line, to output the attributes of field, and for one example of the error it output:

```
in update_fields() - vars(field) =
{
    'field'              : <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: survey>,
    'model'              : <class 'app.survey.models.survey.Survey'>,
    'related_name'       : 'survey_question_related',
    'related_query_name' : None,
    'limit_choices_to'   : {},
    'parent_link'        : False,
    'on_delete'          : <function CASCADE at 0x7efd063bb488>,
    'symmetrical'        : False,
    'multiple'           : True,
    'field_name'         : 'id',
    'related_model'      : <class 'app.survey.models.question.Question'>,
    'hidden'             : False,
    'name'               : 'survey_question_related',
    'many_to_many'       : False
}
```

So Django (or perhaps Python? ) appears to think the expression "field.field" is trying to iterate over ForeignKey. But unless some smartass tomfoolery is going on behind the scenes, that expression is simply an object reference is it not?

It is possible the next line is causing the problem, as I amended this line for Django 3.0.4 because the rel attribute is no longer defined:

```
jr_rel = field.rel if 'rel' in field else field.remote_field
```

But if so then that is equally baffling, because again there seems nothing like anything that could be interpreted as an iteration.

Any ideas? I hope the above info is fairly self-contained

Regards

John Ramsden

P.S. I noticed there is no check that remote_field is an attribute of field.field. So a check for that needs adding. But that is not relevant to this problem.

Comment: `in` requires an iterator

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
jr_rel = field.rel if 'rel' in field else field.remote_field
```

Specifically, `if 'rel' in field`

This is the expression that is trying to iterate over `field`. Perhaps you meant to look at the field's value?